# ¿Como leer $ejecutar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)?

Tags: php, xml, postgresql-9.3

Buenos dias comunidad stackoverflow, solo quisiera que apoyaran a saber cual es mi falla en el codigo php ya que al hacer el while, este no entra y no imprime nada ya vi muchas paginas y nada me a servido, espero que ustedes encuentren la solucion

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request; 
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

//Obtener todos los clientes

$app->get('/actividad/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){

$id = $request->getAttribute('id');


 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM servicios_inmoviliario_alquiler.actividad where id_actividad = '$id'";

     try{
        // Instanciar la base de datos
        $db = new db();

        // Conexión
        $db = $db->conectar();
        $ejecutar = $db->query($consulta);
        $clientes = $ejecutar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $db = null;

        $header=$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];

       if($header == 'application/xml'){

          header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
          echo ("<actividades>");
          while($row = $ejecutar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
             echo("<actividad>");
                echo("<id-actividad>".$row['id_actividad'].</id-actividad>");
                echo("<nombre>".$row['nombre']."</nombre>");
             echo("</actividad>");
          }
          echo("</actividades>");
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

Comment: Reemplazá el while por un `foreach($clientes as $row)` y contame si resultó por favor

Answer (score 1):

El metodo que buscas es [`fechArray`](http://php.net/manual/es/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php), no fetch::

```
//..

header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
echo ("<actividades>");
while($row = $ejecutar->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

 //...
```

Segun la documentacion del metodo [`fetchArray`](http://php.net/manual/es/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php):

> Obtiene una fila de resultados en forma de un array asociativo o
>   indexado o ambos. Por omisión, obtiene ambas formas.

Mientras que el metodo `fetch` solo retorna la primera fila de la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de haber puesto todas las comillas dobles. Por ejemplo en el while, en la segunda linea, tienes:

```
echo("<id-actividad>".$row['id_actividad'].</id-actividad>");
```

Cuando debería ser:

```
echo("<id-actividad>".$row['id_actividad']."</id-actividad>");
```

Aparte de eso puedes usar un var_dump(); de $row para ver que te está devolviendo.

Comment: si eso fue error mio, pero de igual manera no entra al bucle